# Prevent checkbox Label to Toggle the checkBox

Tags: css, angular, checkbox

Here is my checkbox in angular and i want to prevent the default behaviour of it.

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="changeSelectionTo()" [(ngModel)]="isChangeRule">Name</mat-checkbox>
```

Here whenever i click on name label...the checkbox gets toggled which i do not want to..
How can i prevent this from toggling when click on label . I have tried all others post too but I could not come up with the solution . **I can not use jQuery**.

Comment: You could wrap it in a `span` and prevent the click on that, or simply move the label out of the inner text of the component (which may or may not cause style issues with the checkbox).

Comment: i removed inner text , but it was still toggeling

Comment: why don't u use Name outside of element ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]you need to add label after completing the `<mat-checkbox>` tag.

According to your design, you can add style to the `<mat-label>`

Replace your line of code with the below shown code:

```
  <div layout=row>
     <mat-checkbox (change)="changeSelectionTo()" [(ngModel)]="isChangeRule"></mat-checkbox>
    <mat-label> Name </mat-lable>
</div>
```

*above image is generated by below code*

```
<div align="left" class="user-modified-rule">
  <div layout="row">
        <mat-checkbox (change)="changeSelectionTo()" [(ngModel)]="isChangeRule">
        </mat-checkbox>
        <mat-label> 
          <rule></rule>
        </mat-label>
  </div>
</div>

and css code 

.user-modified-rule {
    display: inline-block;
    width : 48%;
}
```

Comment: this is working but this is causing css issues..like checkBox and data is not alligned now which were earlier

Comment: please show me your alignment. For keeping them in single row. you can use <div layout=row> and can just add padding to the mat-label tag.

Comment: `<mat-checkbox><rule>  </rule></mat-checbox>` this shows them in a row ...but when i replaced my `<rule>` component within the `<label>` it shows like div...one below others

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Mike S. comment:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="changeSelectionTo()" [(ngModel)]="isChangeRule">
  <span (click)="myCheck($event)">Name</span>
</mat-checkbox>
```

in your component typescript code:

```
myCheck(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //YOUR LOGIC
}
```